# Bypass login by IP address

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I have a client that wants to use Concrete5.7 for an employee portal. If they are in the building, he does not want them to have to log in to view the site. However, if they are not in the building, he wants them to be able to access the site via a login. The building has a static IP address. Is there a way to over-ride the login or automatically use a specific credential if the user is accessing the site from a specific IP address?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concrete5 [Application Events](https://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/application-events/hooking-application-events)

For example-

```
Events::addListener('on_before_render', function($event) {
    $clientIp = Request::getInstance()->getClientIp();
    if ($clientIp === YOUR_STATIC_IP) {
        $service = Core::make(\Concrete\Core\User\Login\LoginService::class);
        $service->loginByUserID(THE_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_USE);
    }
});
```

This is just an example. Please follow the recommended convention on concrete5 documentation.

Comment: Thanks, biplob! I changed the two lines inside the if statement to just [code]\User::getByUserID(THE_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_USE, true);[/code] and it worked beautifully!

Comment: I see. You're right as you're using 5.7. The LoginService class is introduced in 8.5.x (I guess).